Event Driven Architecture: Populating User Dashboard data
Let's say we are building an application where the user has a dashboard populated with data from multiple services.  For example: On the dashboard, Display pending notifications to be read, fed by notifications service.  Activity history fed by multiple services that report past activity for the user.  And a few more statistics from multiple services.
If I were to design a event driven architecture, how is the data populated in the dashboard? The UI/Frontend will query the dashboard service via API.
(a) Once the user logs in, send a request data event to all dependent service and display the dashboard data from the event responses.
(b) Implement REST API for all services that the dashboard service can query? This is in addition to the services being event driven.
Are there any design patterns for this case in event driven architecture?
Read event driven patterns and found the callbacks was a grey area to me. Also, for just read-only queries, unsure how to address in EDA.

Base on your description, it seems like you are doing microservices.
Imagine you are building a mini data lake.
Reference to the AWS Whitepaper

the "Source" is your other services
the "ETL", assuming you need to something to "process/aggregate" your data.
the "Destination", is your dashboard

There are two options to connect to the "Source".

sync the between MS databases (real time/near time)
use API. push data only when it is needed.

Which one to choose depends on the rest of your design, and other requirements like,

Throughput.
Response time.
Cost.

e.g. #1 will have a better throughput and response time, but will cost more than #2.
With this information, I hope you have enough to make a decision which suit your situation.
